# SQL - Run second Query if count result = 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

Both my SELECT queries work below and return values with as two separate results. What I would like to do is if the first SELECT statement returns a 0 and it will sometimes due to the nature of our work, I would like the second to run ignoring the first one that returns zero if possible. IF the first one returns a result greater than zero then I do not want the second to run.

I have been all over looking and tried different IF ELSE and such but because of the specific date/time formulas used I am thinking it may not be possible or I this may have to be re-written altogether. There is a purpose for this but I will not bore you. Thanks in advance!

```
Declare @StartDate as DateTime
Declare @EndDate as DateTime
Declare @TodaysDate as DateTime
Declare @Previous as DateTime
Declare @Previous2 as DateTime

set @TodaysDate = GETDATE()
set @Previous = DATEADD(day,-1,@TodaysDate)
set @Previous2 = DATEADD(day,-2,@TodaysDate)

-- SELECT Statetment one starts here

set @StartDate = cast(convert(varchar(4), datepart(yyyy, getdate())) + '-' +
convert(varchar(2), datepart(mm, @Previous)) + '-' +
convert(varchar(2), datepart(dd, @Previous)) + ' ' +
'05:00' as datetime)
set @EndDate = cast(convert(varchar(4), datepart(yyyy, getdate())) + '-' +
convert(varchar(2), datepart(mm, @Previous)) + '-' +
convert(varchar(2), datepart(dd, @Previous)) + ' ' +
'16:59' as datetime)

SELECT Count(*) as FirstShfitPrevious
FROM [TOL_PROD_DB].[dbo].[tblLOT_CTRL_Active_Component] 
WHERE  Close_Time_Stamp between @StartDate and @EndDate

-- Query 2 Starts, Declarations already made at beginning

set @StartDate = cast(convert(varchar(4), datepart(yyyy, getdate())) + '-' +
convert(varchar(2), datepart(mm, @Previous2)) + '-' +
convert(varchar(2), datepart(dd, @Previous2)) + ' ' +
'05:00' as datetime)
set @EndDate = cast(convert(varchar(4), datepart(yyyy, getdate())) + '-' +
convert(varchar(2), datepart(mm, @Previous2)) + '-' +
convert(varchar(2), datepart(dd, @Previous2)) + ' ' +
'16:59' as datetime)

SELECT Count(*) as FirstShfitPrevious2
FROM [TOL_PROD_DB].[dbo].[tblLOT_CTRL_Active_Component] 
WHERE  Close_Time_Stamp between @StartDate and @EndDate
```

Comment: Can't you us a simple `if` construct?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to store the value of your first query result in a variable and then then check the value like

```
declare @myVar int

SELECT @myVar = Count(*) as FirstShfitPrevious
FROM [TOL_PROD_DB].[dbo].[tblLOT_CTRL_Active_Component] 
WHERE  Close_Time_Stamp between @StartDate and @EndDate)

if(@myVar = 0)
//Here your second query logic
begin
set @StartDate = cast(convert(varchar(4), datepart(yyyy, getdate())) + '-' +
convert(varchar(2), datepart(mm, @Previous2)) + '-' +
convert(varchar(2), datepart(dd, @Previous2)) + ' ' +
'05:00' as datetime)
set @EndDate = cast(convert(varchar(4), datepart(yyyy, getdate())) + '-' +
convert(varchar(2), datepart(mm, @Previous2)) + '-' +
convert(varchar(2), datepart(dd, @Previous2)) + ' ' +
'16:59' as datetime)

SELECT Count(*) as FirstShfitPrevious2
FROM [TOL_PROD_DB].[dbo].[tblLOT_CTRL_Active_Component] 
WHERE  Close_Time_Stamp between @StartDate and @EndDate
end
```

Comment: or better yet - `select @myVar = count(*)...`

Comment: I tried this before but the issue is the "As" is flagged so the statement fails.If I take out the FirstShiftPrevious it will run but the you just get a message that the wuery ran successfully with no returned data.

Answer (score 0):

use NOT Exists..

```
if NOT Exists
(Select 1  as FirstShfitPrevious--first query
FROM [TOL_PROD_DB].[dbo].[tblLOT_CTRL_Active_Component] 
WHERE  Close_Time_Stamp between @StartDate and @EndDate
)
Begin
SELECT Count(*) as FirstShfitPrevious2--second query
FROM [TOL_PROD_DB].[dbo].[tblLOT_CTRL_Active_Component] 
WHERE  Close_Time_Stamp between @StartDate and @EndDate
END
Else 
Begin
--First query
End
```

Comment: Shift is ending so I will check back tomorrow with this one. Looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

or even that way:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Count(*) as FirstShfitPrevious2
FROM [TOL_PROD_DB].[dbo].[tblLOT_CTRL_Active_Component] 
WHERE  Close_Time_Stamp between @StartDate and @EndDate
GROUP BY CAST(Close_Time_Stamp AS DATE)
ORDER BY CAST(Close_Time_Stamp AS DATE) DESC
```

with period covering both date ranges.

Comment: I tried this and I thank you for the input but the results are the same as my original query where I get same results. I want to eliminate the first result to not even show if at 0.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible (if this is full source). You can't get `count(*)=0` in _one of the groups_. There would be _no group_ at all if no rows match the condition. Note: _**with period covering both date ranges**_. `@startdate` - the lowest one - `dateadd(-2)`

Comment: So none of these suggestions work and again I thank you. I see the problems with the date fudegery going on and the whole zero thing. I think it is impossible to do what I am asking in it's current state. Going to try and work on this "WHILE" thing a co-worker has setup and see if I cannot get the data to do what I want. ITHANKS AGAIN for all your efforts at Stack!